# Does python3 typecast entered input() value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I am writing a raingauge precipitation calculator based in the radius of the raingauge. When I run my script, I have this error message:

```
Type de raingauge radius [cm]: 5.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pluviometro.py", line 27, in <module>
    area_bocal = (pi * (raio_bocal * raio_bocal)) # cm.cm
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

I am using 
`raio_bocal = input("Type de raingauge radius [cm]:")`
for data input. When using `Python2` the typecasting was automatic.

How can I have a `float` entered value using `python3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast to float, input returns a string in python3:

```
float(input("Type de raingauge radius [cm]:"))
```

Probably safer use a while loop with a try/except when casting input.

```
while True:
   inp = input("Type de raingauge radius [cm]:")
   try:
       raio_bocal  = float(inp)
       break
   except ValueError:
       print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: whould it has any performatic difference if I code this way?
 ```while True:
   try:  
       raio_bocal  = float(input("Type de raingauge radius [cm]:") )
       break
   except ValueError:
       print("Invalid input")```

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

> The function then reads a line from input, **converts it to a string** (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that

So you need to type cast it to `float` explicitly

```
raio_bocal = float(input("Type de raingauge radius [cm]:"))
```